# C2DM - Limitation Gmail Account

Tags: android, gmail, android-c2dm, user-accounts

It seems the C2DM is just connected to Gmail accounts, and so it cannot be used by people who doesn't have it among the accounts on the phone.

Have you found a solution to bypass this limitation (I dunno, maybe having a batch of ready gmail accounts to offer to the user that is installing the c2dm-app) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the user has to have an Gmail account, but he needs an Google Account as the push notification mechanism only works with phones which have installed the Android Market app and registered their Google account to it.

There are some other third party solutions. E.g. [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/).

Comment: And what if he doesn't have a Google account? 
Have you ever experienced UA? what are pros and cons? 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with UA yet, I just read about it. As far as I know the way C2DM works is that the Android Market app handles an open connection to some Google servers which allows the server to  actively send  (push) messages to the client. If the user doesn't have a Google account then he cannot use the Android Market app and therefore cannot receive push notifications via C2DM. To use UA you need to integrate the UA library into your app. It contains a service which will handle the receiving of push notifications. I think it also works by keeping a connection to the UA server open.

Comment: I read somewhere UA needs to work with Urban Mail app. Give a look at http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The C2DM is an interface for the Google service that push the mail, calendar and other google stuff because of that the mobile device needs a gmail (gmail or google account).

Urban Airship abstracts your server-side if you are doing push to diferent devices (mostly android and iOs) so I don't think it's a solution neither.

The only way to make this is create your own service that  receive the push in background, maybe using xmpp ([asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/)) or comet systems.

Comment: thank, I will give a look to UA (but it seems that you have to install AirMail app onto their device, so it's not such a good solution in my case) and XMPP protocol..but still I hope to find a solution to my problem..